# CSS Parallax - image 'splitting' and showing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, parallax

This relates to the following site: http://www.sandbox.sharonblance.com/

I have an issue with the parallax images frequently showing 'split'. Refer to the sample image.
[image: here you can see the bottom and the top of the image]
Do you have any advice on how to resolve this issue? I'm not sure where to even begin to track this down. Please note that this is a theme that I purchased, but the author has not been forthcoming with assistance. I love the theme otherwise, as long as I can resolve this issue!

BROWSER INFO:
I am seeing the problem on Chrome on windows 7 and windows 8, in firefox (v22) and chrome (28.0.1500.95) and IE 10. Sometimes it is okay when the page first loads, but if you refresh it screws up?

The scrolling also quite jerky and not smooth?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem on Chrome on Mac.

Comment: I don't see a problem either - Chrome on Linux.

Comment: I am seeing the problem on Chrome on windows 7 and windows 8, in firefox (v22) and chrome (28.0.1500.95) and IE 10. Sometimes it is okay when the page first loads, but if you refresh it screws up?

Comment: Any news about how to resolve it?

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem as you said, and i found the solution to fix that, You should using image with height more b